# Opportunity lookup field on opportunity VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce

so I'm working on transfering some contents from one opportunityA to another opportunityB (for instance, products) via a button on the opportunityA page.

Upon the button press, I want a VF page with only one input field (the opportunity lookup field) so I can pass the ID of that user selected opportunityB to my custom controller for further logic.

Since I'm utilizing the opportunity standard controller to get the ID via the button on the opportunityA page, how do I create  the look up opportunity  field on my VF page with the opp standard controller?

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" extensions="transferprod">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:inputField value="{????}"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I know one way is to create an opportunity lookup field on opportunity, but is there another way so I dont create this reduntant field....

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Opportunity StandardController use `OpportunityLineItem` standardController to lookup the Opportunity

Behind the custom button, use URL to call the page and pass the Opportunity Id

```
/apex/yourPage?OpptyId={!Opportunity.Id}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="OpportunityLineItem" extensions="transferprod">
  <apex:form>
  Previous Opportunity:
  <apex:inputText value="{!OpportunityId}"/>
  <br/>
  Other Opportunity:

  <apex:inputField value="{!newopptyLineItem.OpportunityId}"/>

  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class transferprod
{
    public OpportunityLineItem opptyLineItem {get;set;}
    public OpportunityLineItem newopptyLineItem {get;set;}

    public String OpportunityId {get;set;}
    public transferprod(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        OpportunityId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('OpptyId');

        newopptyLineItem  = new OpportunityLineItem();
    }
}
```

**Result**

Output will look like this:

You can display previous opportunity name, instead of id.

[image: result]

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The opportunity on which the button was pressed is preserved. Now, I want to the user to select another opportunity to which to transfer the contents to...so on the new VF page, they'll lookup the opportunity. How do I make this lookup field on the VF page?

Comment: So there is the oppIdA thats passed via button press, then there is oppIdB which is selected by user on the lookup field.

Comment: do you want to select OpportunityA again in this page?

Comment: No, I will be selecting OpportunityB on the lookup field. Then, I use will the OpportunityA.id (passed) to copy the contents to this selected OpportunityB.id in controller.

Comment: Well, my answer would have pretty much been exactly this. The only difference is that instead of creating an `Opportunity` in the extension to use for the input field, I used an `OpportunityLineItem` (because I don't think `Opportunity.Id` has the creatable attribute, but `OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId` does have that attribute). @Sammy7, the key thing to realize here is that you can avoid creating a field by using a "dummy" object in your extension (`OpportunityLineItem` in this case) that already has a field with the properties you're looking for (lookup to `Opportunity`).

Comment: @SantanuBoral A custom controller is completely unnecessary here. A dummy object in a controller extension (like I mention in my previous comment) will do the job just fine.